# error processing package initramfs-tools No space left on device

Tags: live-usb, 14.04

I have a persistent copy of Ubuntu (made with pendrivelinux) on a 4GB pendrive. I'm trying to install ENG language support (after accidentally deleting it) but I get an error that says:
`error processing package initramfs-tools No space left on device.`

I already did

```
sudo apt-get remove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and after that df -h is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            2.7G  1.9G  742M  72% /
udev            3.0G  4.0K  3.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           599M  1.2M  598M   1% /run
/dev/sdc1       3.8G  3.8G  2.0K 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      936M  936M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.0G  2.4M  3.0G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.0G  336K  3.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  1.2T  652G  66% /media/ubuntu/USB-HDD
/dev/loop1      2.7G  1.9G  742M  72% /media/ubuntu/casper-rw
/dev/sda3       459G  370G   89G  81% /media/ubuntu/Packard Bell
/dev/sda4       459G  121G  339G  27% /media/ubuntu/DATA
```

Is there anything I could do? It's my first time using Ubuntu, btw.

**ETA:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1a72457f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    29362175    14680064   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    29362176    29566975      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        29566976   991008767   480720896    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       991008768  1953521663   481256448    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa48d32de

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63  3907024064  1953512001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
126 heads, 22 sectors/track, 2825 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe4ad4591

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048     7831551     3914752    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: did you install Ubuntu via wubi?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used this http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/ and the 14.04 distro

Comment: @Barbara Can you provide output from:          sudo fdisk -l       Thanks

Comment: @Barbara Did you try emptying the trash?

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes, the trash is empty. Added the output to the original post.

Comment: @Barbara your flash drive is mounted at /cdrom. I don't see a persistence partition on it. Do you have any user data on it or just the system?

Comment: @ElderGeek Do you mean if it is a fresh install? Then, no. I did some tweaking, uninstalled some software and uploaded new one. The usb was empty, though. I formatted it before the use and then pendrivelinux.com did everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14155/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-barbara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat and your requirements that the end result be a portable video editing solution, I recommend that you start over with your live media and install to a larger media and make your modifications to the installation on the larger media rather than the live media.